# Image map with Qtip2 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have an image map using Qtip, and I want the tooltip to show up on both the left eye and the right eye, but the tooltip is not showing up.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('area[alt]').qtip(
  {
     content: {
          attr: 'alt'
     },
     hide: {
          fixed: true,
          delay: 500
     },
     style: {
      classes: 'qtip-tipsy qtip-shadow'
     },
     position: {
      viewport: $(window)
     }
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<map name="Koala">
<area alt="Left Eye" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#" />
<area alt="Right Eye" shape="rect" coords="641,405,681,448" href="#" />
<!-- .... more hotspots would be listed here -->
</map>
```

When I try this code the Qtip does not show up at all and I can not figure out why, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the demo fiddle that was provided in the qtip page 
http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/v2WPz/

and then modify yours to reflect the changes you want and it should be working.

Here is the final version:

jsfiddle.net/v2WPz/775

```
<div id="demo-imagemap">
    <h3>United States of America</h3>

    <img border="0" usemap="#statesMap" alt="USA" src="http://www.wallpaperpimper.com/wallpaper/Animal/Koalas/Koala-Bear-Australia-1-1024x768.jpg">
    <map id="statesMap" name="statesMap">
<area alt="Left Eye" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#" />
<area alt="Right Eye" shape="rect" coords="641,405,681,448" href="#" />
    </map>

    <p class="attribution">
        imagemap courtesy of <a href="http://www.americanbanker.com/state/state.html">American Banker</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // We'll target all AREA elements with alt tags (Don't target the map element!!!)
    $('area[alt]').qtip(
    {
        content: {
            attr: 'alt' // Use the ALT attribute of the area map for the content
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you try the selector in say the Firebug console window do you see it returning objects? Are you able to have the qtip work on other elements in the page?

Comment: Yes I can get the qtip to work on say an <a href...> tag. When I hovered over the eyes while viewing the console window, this error popped up: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Comment: Do you know how to define a plugin? I wonder if I have to use the image map plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... are you area's defined correctly? Can you set the href property and have that work?

Comment: When I look at the demo on http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#imagemap this should be fairly straightforward and if you are still having problems you probably need to start reducing any extras you have built into your project to ensure you are not getting errors from other items.

Comment: Yes i can get a normal hyperlink href property to display the qtip. Its very straightforward which is making this more frustrating! In the documentation, he has image map as a plugin. I tried putting it into my page but it says plugin is not defined

Comment: When I look at the fiddle I do not see any plugin, and it works fine, can you copy your stuff over to have it modify the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/v2WPz/

Comment: How bizarre, I changed the picture to my Koala picture, and replaced with my two coordinates, and voila! Here is the new fiddle with it.. http://jsfiddle.net/v2WPz/775/

Comment: Oh well the important thing is it's working, hope I helped you get there.

Comment: I tested it out on my website and it works! Thank you soooo much for all your help and taking the time to work this problem out with me! You helped me from throwing my computer across the room :)

Comment: If i had enough reputation I would upvote your replies, want to make the new fiddle a separate answer?